# Message signature was incorrect

Tags: support, status-completed, openid, login, google-openid

I'm getting an error trying to login to Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow with my [Google Apps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Apps) account (I remoted into my home computer to post this). The message I get is "Message signature was incorrect".

[image]

Comment: I saw this as well using my Gmail account. (Error occurs in both Firefox and Chrome.) I had to log in with my alternate OpenID. Is this due to a change in the engine or with Google?

Comment: I see this with my gmail account too.  Had to use my alternate as well.

Comment: It's just started today, around 10am eastern time - I was logged in, I restarted my computer, I logged back in, and got that message. Took me most of the day to remember I had linked my facebook as well or I'd have reported it earlier.

Comment: I had this problem earlier this morning, but now (1:51 pm eastern), I could log in with my Google open id.

Comment: This happened as well with my Google Apps login. I was able to use the Facebook login as a workaround, and the Google Apps login seems to be working again now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Google appears to be suffering some sort of outage, it's not just a Stack Exchange problem.

As a work around, if you register a new account at [openid.stackexchange.com](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register) with the *same* email address that is associated with your Google account you'll be able to login.  We auto-magically map up users with the same verified email address basically.  Login in via Facebook will also work, for similar reasons.

Note that the email must be *exactly* the same, so don't use any `+soworkdaround` or the wrong choice of `gmail` vs. `googlemail`.

Note: this seems to be intermittent or random, as many Google OpenID users are still able to login.

Comment: Thanks.  I was finally was able to get in with Google.

Comment: This is what I was looking for when I posted my 'answer' as user471803

Comment: I usually sign in via my Google Apps account, which didn't work earlier this morning. On a hunch, I tried the Facebook login, and it worked, surprisingly. Now I know why, since the email addresses for both accounts are the same.