# Line break at the wrong spot in comment meta data

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-interface

See sample image below (red box in it). For a while I was wondering what the number 29 was after *Macro*. Initially thought it was his repuration points.

Can the code add a non-breaking space somehow between the number and "minutes ago"? What do the UI experts think?

Apologies if this seems nitpicking. That wasn't the intention!

[image]

(It is a tiny matter; so maybe it's not worth a fix.)

Comment: @Anna, since you tagged this as by design, is there any official stance on writing `Stack Exchange` vs `Stack&nbsp;Exchange`?

Comment: @Arjan I'm not aware of any debate around that, nevermind an official stance. If the trademark guidelines don't specify otherwise, I think either is fine.

Comment: Okay, too bad, @Anna ;-) (I dislike seeing `Stack&nbsp;Exchange` in the Markdown, and I dislike seeing a lot of whitespace at the end of a line when a browser wraps the two words together, especially on small screens on which lines might be short. But I'm not losing any sleep over it.)

Comment: (As an aside, @Anna, the "debate" about `&nbsp;` so far is only in comments, like [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130567/message-signature-incorrect-when-trying-to-login#comment359122_130567). Too bad I cannot search my comments! `;-)`)

Comment: Whether or not not breaking "Stack Exchange" is important, a non-breaking space between a measurement and its unit (e.g, 1 lb, 29 minutes, etc.) seems like a good idea, and it's suggested by at least some people.  E.g., the accepted answer to http://english.stackexchange.com/q/28467/45891 says "It is advisable to use a non-breaking space (also known as a hard space) to prevent the end-of-line displacement of elements that would be awkward at the beginning of a new line: in expressions in which figures and abbreviations (or symbols) are separated by a space (e.g. 17 kg, AD 565, 2:50 pm);"

Answer (score 5):

There's a related question on English.SE: [When is it appropriate to use non-breaking spaces?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/28467/45891), and one of the important cases that's brough up is between numbers and units. The accepted answer cites [Wikipedia's Manual of Style on Non-breaking spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style#Non-breaking_spaces):

> It is advisable to use a non-breaking space to prevent the end-of-line
>   displacement of elements that would be awkward at the beginning of a
>   new line:
>
> in expressions in which figures and their related unit abbreviations
>   or symbols are separated by a space (e.g. 17 kg, AD 565, 2:50 pm);

Between "29" and "minutes" seems like just such a case.

Answer (score 1):

If this is deemed necessary to fix, the simplest solution would be to place an intentional line break prior to the hyphen before the username, and right-align the newly created "time-stamped signature" line.

Comment: Since it's a nitpicky question, I'll pick nits: It's a endash, not a hyphen: (endash: –) (hyphen: -) (for completeness, emdash: —).  An intentional line break doesn't really seem simpler than a non-breaking space between "29" and "minutes", but the latter has traditional typesetting rules in support of it.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor - I think you might need to be banished back to the depths of http://english.stackexchange.com/ . :P

Comment: It's not even english.SE that got me to this point (though it's what I quoted in [my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204708/225437)), but rather working with TeX and LaTeX.

Comment: For the record, I had an experiment and the right-aligned signature does look pretty schmick. http://matthew.kerwin.net.au/misc/meta.stack-exchange.comment.png

Comment: @MattyK - not sure if I like float over non-float, but I do like the right-align.  If it was done that way, I wouldn't keep the <s>hy</s>ENDASH.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree, I think that's fairly self explanatory that the wrapping has occured just as you'd expect `white-space: nowrap` to.

Besides, reputation isn't shown beside a comment, otherwise I'd support your case (if that were the case, it may read Macro 2345 29 before the line break, which would be a littler *uglier* :)).