# Wrong message on questions page

Tags: support, questions, community-user

I opened the [active questions page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions) on meta.stackoverflow.com and I saw this:

> [image]
>
> "modified [39 mins ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171672/line-break-at-wrong-spot-in-comment-meta-data/?lastactivity)"

Clicking on the **last activity link** it goes me to the question page.
I don't see anything modified by Community♦ on [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171672/line-break-at-wrong-spot-in-comment-meta-data).

I saw that this thing happens frequently.

Is this a problem/bug, or I didn't understand something? Which is the answer?

Comment: That's just the community user bumping the question. It does so occasionally. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community

Comment: I wrote a [userscript](http://stackapps.com/questions/4134/) that makes the last activity more descriptive, and would probably avoid this kind of confusion: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eP55N.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably just the Community user bumping an old question. Happens every hour or so.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From the  [Who is the Community user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) post. 

Part of is duty is to bump unanswered question so they get attention. Doesn't mean it (*he* ?) changed something in the post.

```
Hi, I'm not really a person.

I'm a background process that helps keep [Meta] [Stack Overflow / Server Fault / Super User] clean!

I do things like

    Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention
    Own community questions and answers so nobody gets unnecessary reputation from them
    Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that get permanently deleted
    Own suggested edits from anonymous users
```

Take a look at the first point.