# Why is this Docker question off-topic?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

This question is clearly not off topic, as it *directly pertains to Docker*. I think this belongs on here, possibly Server Fault, but there is a tag for it here. I had to remove all references to my ***use-case*** because people thought it was off-topic.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405059/java-instances-on-docker

Comment: You know, why does the Docker tag even exist? Docker is strictly for environments, not coding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's off-topic because it doesn't *directly pertain to programming*, just setting up an environment to run a program.

Try on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), or may be [Super User](https://superuser.com/). I'd also recommend not putting "Minecraft" in the title; it can trigger some people the wrong way.

Comment: Can you or someone else cast a migration vote?

Comment: You'd need to flag it, @IanCarroll, but only after you edit it to make it more substantial and clear what it is that you're doing. Check out the FAQ of the site you wish to migrate to and make sure your post meets the guidelines. This increases the chance the target community will accept your post.

Comment: @Richard Well, after thinking about it, I have an excuse. You'd most likely need to program something to run in the environment. :P

Comment: @PeterMortensen Why on earth did you link to wikipedia?

Comment: Ah, and I'm not the only one who [really dislikes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130567/message-signature-incorrect-when-trying-to-login#comment359122_130567) the `&nbsp;` in things such as `Super&nbsp;User`, @Peter... :-)

Comment: Does this mean that all docker related questions are off-topic? It does not appear as if the community agrees with that, seeing all the docker questions posted and answered on Stackoverflow...

Comment: As a DevOps programmer, this is relevant to what I do, but OK, it doesn't go on StackOverflow. It doesn't seem like it belongs on Super User, since that's for "computer enthusiasts and power users", neither of which apply. Doesn't seem to belong on Server Fault either because that's "for professional system and network administrators", which I'm not either. So where _should_ questions about Docker go? And questions about Puppet or Chef seem like they're in the same category.