# Is StackExchange OAuth broken?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, login, oauth

Logging in to stackexchange.com via oauth (Google) was temporarily not working, but it's solved now.

While logged in my gmail account ( and also happily logged in to StackOverflow: I can see my account details there); when I try to login t StackExchange, using Google as my OAuth, this is what I get:

```
Unable to log in with your OpenID provider:

Message signature was incorrect.
```

This is now solved; but I'm unable to point to what solved the issue: I did not clear cookies or restart browser, log out/back in to gmail, etc.

It seems to be a transient issue - I'm leaving this question here in case it happens again and folks want to add details.

Thanks to all who have chimed in!

Comment: Might be something on your side, see answers [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130567/message-signature-incorrect-when-trying-to-login)

Comment: What do you mean by "access StackExchange"? Are you going to stackexchange.com or a Q&A site?

Comment: While I'm on the subject, what do you mean by "link it to another site"? Please edit your question to describe the steps you're taking.

Comment: I was trying to login on stackexchange.com - it was clearly something either transient or, as @ShadowWizard pointed out, maybe on my side: tried again just now and it worked (note I did not clear cookies, re-start browser or logged out/in from gmail).  Thanks for help, folks, I'll also edit the question with steps for future reference.

Comment: @Marco Glad to hear it resolved itself. Marking this bug as norepro for now. Thanks for following up!

Comment: So most likely something was off on Google's side.